# Deploy compiled Rails app to Java server on Heroku

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, heroku, jruby, warbler

What are the steps I need to take to deploy my compiled jruby rails application(with warbler gem) to heroku Java servers?

I don't know Java so I hope you can help with the actions I need to take. For example, how I deal with the database connection? What configuration I need?

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/moving-an-existing-rails-app-to-run-on-jruby

Comment: I did that already, the problem is how do I work with the war file.

Answer (score 1):

for deploying your Rails application as a war archive you should follow the Java web-app runner [guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-webapp-runner) ... although it does require some Java domain knowledge - mostly around Maven.

probably the easiest thing is [deployment using the toolbelt plugin](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/war-deployment#deployment-with-the-heroku-toolbelt) `heroku deploy:war --war <path_to_war_file>` since it assumes you have packaged the .war on your own locally ...

**NOTE:** be advised that if you'd follow the [migrating to JRuby](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/moving-an-existing-rails-app-to-run-on-jruby) guide than you'll end up deploying without any .war packaging being involved in the process (similar to how you deploy with MRI)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I don't understand 2 things:
1)The connection file to Heroku DB should be included in the war?

2)Warbler doesn't generate any POM file, how do I get that?

I tried deploying the war using toolbelt plugin but I get an error about jdk version not matching, even though I have installed(and running) 1.8 and toolbelt supports that

Comment: Check that your `java -version` command reports Java 8, and check that your JAVA_HOME env var is set correctly.